# Базовый шаблон и роутинг AngularJS + UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing, angularjs-controller

Только начал свой путь по освоению AngularJS и наткнулся на проблемы с роутингом. Стандартный меня не устраивает тем, что вся страница обновляется. Мне же нужно всегда одно и то же меню, висящий топ со своим контроллером и меняющийся, в зависимости от действий пользователя, блок контента. Накопал естественно `angular-ui-router`, сделал следующее ...

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title ng-bind="title"></title>
        <!-- подключаем app.css и bootstrap.css -->
        <!-- подключаем jquery, bootstrap, angular, angular-ui-router -->
        <!-- подключаем app.js и pages/start/controller.js -->
    </head>

    <body ng-cloak>
        <div class="ui-top"><!-- Верхняя шапка с плюшками --></div>
        <div class="ui-main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in mainMenu">
                        <a ui-sref="{{item.path}}">{{item.name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-main-conteiner">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js:**

```
angular.module("app", [ 'app.start', 'ui.router' ])
.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    '$locationProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state("start", {
            url: '/start',
            templateUrl: 'pages/start/index.html',
            controller: 'StartCtrl'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("start");
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])

.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {

    $scope.title = "MyFirst Page in Angular";
    $scope.mainMenu = [
        {
            name: 'Menu 1',
            path: '/path1'
        },
        {
            name: 'Menu 2',
            path: '/path2'
        }
    ];
}]);
```

**pages/start/controller.js:**

```
angular.module('app.start', [ 'ui.router' ])

.controller('StartCtrl',['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Message from StartCtrl";
}]);
```

**pages/start/index.html:**

```
<h2>Start Page</h2>
<p>{{message}}</p>
```

`StartCtrl` не отрабатывает и в `<div ng-view></div>` ничего не отображается ... Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Есть какие-то ошибки в консоли браузера?

Comment: Никаких ошибок нет ... Более того, есть удачный get запрос на pages/start/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Директива `ng-view` для модуля *ngRoute*. Для *ui-router* нужно использовать `ui-view`.

Comment: Ё-моё .... Спасибо!